# How to detect when ics file clicked

Tags: android

How to find when user clicks the ics file ? In android programmatically

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an `ACTION_VIEW` `<intent-filter>` for an activity that responds to whatever the ICS MIME type is. That will not help for files just stored locally but should work for links to ICS files on Web pages (assuming properly-configured Web servers).